# Sending email alerts to multiple to addresses

Tags: mule

While sending email alerts i have multiple email groups

email group for english speaking users,
email group for spanish speaking users,
email group for portuguese speaking users

A template (using velocity templates) is defined to each mail user group. Now email alerts have to be sent to all 3 user groups with different contents defined in the template. How do i set up the outbound email endpoint and send emails.

Solution ( after the reply received)

```
<all doc:name="All">
<processor-chain >
    <custom-transformer class="xxx.xxx.xxx.transformer.VelocityMessageTransformer" doc:name="Mails to en_US">
        <spring:property name="templateName" value="templates/EMAIL-MESSAGE.vm"/>
    </custom-transformer>
    <smtps:outbound-endpoint host="smtp.gmail.com" user="myemail%40gmail.com" password="XXXX" responseTimeout="10000"  doc:name="SMTP" subject="Mails to en_US" from="myemail@gmail.com" to="myemail@gmail.com"/>
    <custom-transformer class="xxx.xxx.xxx.transformer.SetOriginalPayloadTransformer" doc:name="Set Payload to Orignal Payload"/>
    <custom-transformer class="xxx.xxx.xxx.transformer.VelocityMessageTransformer" doc:name="Mails to es_ES">
        <spring:property name="templateName" value="templates/EMAIL-MESSAGE-Spanish.vm"/>
    </custom-transformer>
    <smtps:outbound-endpoint host="smtp.gmail.com" user="myemail%40gmail.com" password="XXXX" responseTimeout="10000"  doc:name="SMTP" subject="Mails to es_ES" from="myemail@gmail.com" to="myemail@gmail.com"/>
    <custom-transformer class="xxx.xxx.xxx.transformer.SetOriginalPayloadTransformer" doc:name="Set Payload to Orignal Payload"/>
    <custom-transformer class="xxx.xxx.xxx.transformer.VelocityMessageTransformer" doc:name="Mails to pt_PT">
        <spring:property name="templateName" value="templates/EMAIL-MESSAGE-Portugese.vm"/>
    </custom-transformer>
    <smtps:outbound-endpoint host="smtp.gmail.com" user="myemail%40gmail.com" password="XXXX" responseTimeout="10000"  doc:name="SMTP" subject="Mails to pt_PT" from="myemail@gmail.com" to="myemail@gmail.com"/>
    <custom-transformer class="xxx.xxx.xxx.transformer.SetOriginalPayloadTransformer" doc:name="Set Payload to Orignal Payload"/>
</processor-chain>
</all>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an `<all>` message processor with in it one `processor-chain` for each email group. In this chain, generate the right content and use an `smtp:outbound-endpoint` to send it.